# Prove or disprove that if A, B, and C are nonempty sets and $A \times B = A \times C$, then $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I worked out the following:

$A \times B = \{(a,b) | a \in A \land b \in B\} $, since $A \times B = A \times C$ then the following is true:

$A \times C = \{(a,b) | a \in A \land b \in C\} $, therefore $\forall b(b \in B \rightarrow b \in C) \equiv B \subseteq C$

and that without loss of generality $C \subseteq B \therefore B = C$.

But I'm not clear on how this proves that $B \subseteq C$ vs. $B \subset C?$

Comment: They're practically the same notation in most conventions. Sometimes $\subset$ is used as a proper subset but this is ambiguous and I like to use is $\subsetneq$

Comment: That "therfore" is grasphing at straws.  Why is it necessary for the sets to be not empty?

Comment: You've only gone half way.  You do the same argument that for all $c\in C\to c\in B $.

Comment: @Clayton.  That doesn't make it necessary.  It is necessary because if A is empty, give a example with A /= B.

Comment: I misunderstood your statement, @WilliamElliot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $A$ is not empty and $A\times B = A \times C$.
Let $a$ be an element of $A$.

If $x \in B$, then $(a,x) \in A\times B$.
So $(a,x) \in A\times C$, hence $x \in C$.
Thus $B \subseteq C$.
Similarly $C \subseteq B$.

Comment: really, MathJax is not that hard..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.   Nothing much is not that hard with a small touch screen.

Comment: I do type MathJax on a phone. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\Bbb R^\infty$, $B=\Bbb R$, and $C=\Bbb R^2$. Then $$A\times B=A\times C$$ but clearly $B\neq C$.

Comment: A×B = A×C is just a natural bijection, it is not equality.  (a, (b,c)) and  ((a,b), c) are not equal but consider such for convenience.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: True; I'll leave the answer up in case the OP finds it helpful.

Comment: So to confirm, the question is asking me to prove $(A \times B = A \times C) \to (B=C)$ and the above example shows that $(A \times B = A \times C) \land (B \neq C) \equiv T \therefore$ The statement B = C is false?

Comment: @Elliott: As sets, these two behave **very** similarly, which is why I jumped to this counterexample. However, you have to look at the elements in each one to see that the two sets *aren't* actually equal; that is, elements on the left look like $(\mathbf{a},b)$ where $\mathbf a\in\Bbb R^\infty$ and $b\in\Bbb R$ while elements on the right look like $(\mathbf a, \mathbf c)$ where $\mathbf c\in\Bbb R^2$.